# Can't call Auth::user() on controller's constructor

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

I'm trying to check if the user has permission to a certain model. Up until now (with Laravel 5.2), I added this code at the constructor:

```
public function __construct()
{
    if (!Auth::user()->hasPermission('usergroups')) {
        abort(404);
    }
}
```

Now, after upgrading to Laravel 5.3, `Auth::user()` returns `null` when being called from the controller's constructor. If I call it within any other method of the class, it returns the currently logged in user.

Any Ideas why?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

See [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/upgrade#upgrade-5.3.0):

> **Session In The Constructor**
>
> In previous versions of Laravel, you could access session variables or
>   the authenticated user in your controller's constructor. This was
>   never intended to be an explicit feature of the framework. In Laravel
>   5.3, you can't access the session or authenticated user in your controller's constructor because the middleware has not run yet.
>
> As an alternative, you may define a Closure based middleware directly
>   in your controller's constructor. Before using this feature, make sure
>   that your application is running Laravel 5.3.4 or above:
>
> ```
> <?php
>
> namespace App\Http\Controllers;
>
> use App\User;
> use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
> use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
>
> class ProjectController extends Controller
> {
>     /**
>      * All of the current user's projects.
>      */
>     protected $projects;
>
>     /**
>      * Create a new controller instance.
>      *
>      * @return void
>      */
>     public function __construct()
>     {
>         $this->middleware(function ($request, $next) {
>             $this->projects = Auth::user()->projects;
>
>             return $next($request);
>         });
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> Of course, you may also access the request session data or
>   authenticated user by type-hinting the Illuminate\Http\Request class
>   on your controller action:
>
> ```
> /**
>  * Show all of the projects for the current user.
>  *
>  * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
>  * @return Response
>  */
> public function index(Request $request)
> {
>     $projects = $request->user()->projects;
>
>     $value = $request->session()->get('key');
>
>     //
> }
> ```

Comment: Thank you Samsquanch, you saved the day !

Comment: If you're getting funky header errors, you probably forgot `return $next($request);` or your redirect doesn't work (and there is no `return $next($request);`)

Comment: Another alternative may be extending Larave'ls callAction() method within controller, which will allow to use auth()->user() before executing a specific action, as explained in this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34261796/before-executing-action-in-laravel-5-1

Answer (score 5):

```
class StudentController extends Controller
{

    public $role;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware(function ($request, $next) {  
        if (!Auth::user()->hasPermission('usergroups')) {
            abort(404);
        }
            return $next($request);
        });
    }
}
```

Hope help you!!!

Update:
Get your code inside

```
$this->middleware(function ($request, $next) {
//your code
return $next($request);
});
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! Please edit your post and some explanation what you did, why it solves the issue and how it relates to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Because you're attempting to access the instance before the middleware even fires. You can use `request()->user()` instead.