# Laravel 5.3 Auth check - Session store not set on request

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

I'm starting a new app in 5.3 and want to implement the solution for the auth check as stated [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/upgrade#5.3-session-in-constructors)

I'm using the register and login models out of the box for 5.3. I've only worked a month on Laravel so struggling to fully interpret the solution.
I moved the HomeController.php to the Auth folder under controllers and added the following `use` statements: `use App\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;`
 I editd the HomeController constructor as follow:

```
public function __construct()
{
    //$this->middleware('auth');
    $this->middleware(function ($request, $next) {
        $this->user= Auth::user();
        return $next($request);
    });
}
```

Here's my controller screenshot. [image]

Still get the "Session store not set on request." error when I try to register.
I read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39175252/cant-call-authuser-on-controllers-constructor) as well, but need more guidance please. Just want to get 5.3 out of the box authentication to work.
Here is my Auth folder structure.

[image]

Here is my routes/web.php

[image]

RouteServiceProvider.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\RouteServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;

class RouteServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
 protected $namespace = 'App\Http\Controllers';

/**
 * Define your route model bindings, pattern filters, etc.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function boot()
{
    //

    parent::boot();
}

/**
 * Define the routes for the application.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function map()
{
    $this->mapApiRoutes();

    $this->mapWebRoutes();

    //
}

/**
 * Define the "web" routes for the application.
 *
 * These routes all receive session state, CSRF protection, etc.
 *
 * @return void
 */
protected function mapWebRoutes()
{
    Route::group([
        'middleware' => 'web',
        'namespace' => $this->namespace,
    ], function ($router) {
        require base_path('routes/web.php');
    });
}

/**
 * Define the "api" routes for the application.
 *
 * These routes are typically stateless.
 *
 * @return void
 */
protected function mapApiRoutes()
{
    Route::group([
        'middleware' => 'api',
        'namespace' => $this->namespace,
        'prefix' => 'api',
    ], function ($router) {
        require base_path('routes/api.php');
    });
}
}
```

The Kernel:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel as HttpKernel;

class Kernel extends HttpKernel
{
/**
 * The application's global HTTP middleware stack.
 *
 * These middleware are run during every request to your application.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $middleware = [
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
];

/**
 * The application's route middleware groups.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,                    
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    ],

    'api' => [
        'throttle:60,1',
        'bindings',
    ],
];

/**
 * The application's route middleware.
 *
 * These middleware may be assigned to groups or used individually.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'auth' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
    'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
    'bindings' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
    'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
    'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
];
}
```

Comment: What does your **RouteServiceProvider.php** file look like? As I have an idea what the problem may be.

Comment: Hi. That’s the wrong file. There should be one in your **app/Providers/** folder.

Comment: No problem. What about your **app/Http/Kernel.php** file?

Comment: Hmm. It’s not what I thought it may be (middleware groups missing from kernel). Are you still getting the error?

Comment: Yes, still do. Pretty sure it's related to this https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/upgrade#5.3-session-in-constructors but don't know how to implement the proposed solution.

Comment: what version of 5.3 do you have installed?  `php artisan --version`

Comment: also double check that your `SESSION_DRIVER` is set in your `.env` file