# Laravel 5.5 get user auth in contoller constructor

Tags: authentication, laravel-5.5

Is there any way to get user Auth data in controller constructor?

this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/39175335/657556 is not working for me.

Comment: Can you give an example on what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

You have to `use` it on the top of the controller as follows just below namespace.

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
```