# how to implement multiuser (4 user types) authentification in laravel with two linked tables - roles and users

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I'm making my very first laravel (and programming at all) project. I want to make multi-user authentification system with just two tables: users and roles
The tables codes are shown below 
users

```
$table->increments('id'); 
$table->string('name'); 
$table->string('email')->unique(); 
$table->integer('role_id')->unsigned(); 
$table->foreign('role_id')->references('id')->on('roles'); 
$table->string('password'); 
$table->rememberToken(); 
$table->timestamps();
```

roles

```
$table->increments('id'); 
$table->string('role');
```

The authentification is implemented using laravel command

```
php artisan make:auth
```

I've created midllewares admin, user1, user2 and user3 using laravel command

```
php artisan make:midlleware
```

How to implement middleware assigment based on role_id from users table that is assigned to user during registration?
I had an idea to make something like this: 
in HomeController

```
public function __construct()
    {     
       if($this->role_id=="1"){
        $this->middleware('admin'); }

       if($this->role_id=="2"){
        $this->middleware('user0');  }

       if($this->role_id=="3"){
        $this->middleware('user1'); }

       if($this->role_id=="4"){
        $this->middleware('user2'); }
    }
```

But I have an error 
Undefined property: App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::$role_id

Then I created __toString method in Controller

```
public function __toString()
    {
      return $this->role_id;
    }
```

I try to echo $this to see it's format, I got an error 
Method App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::__toString() must not throw an exception, caught ErrorException: Undefined property: App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::$role_id

Am I on a good tracks? Or can anyone give me an advice what is the easiest way to implement multiuser auth but with no , or just one additional (permissions) table ?

Thanks

Comment: I am pretty sure there will be an Addin/Plugin/.... for this if you look for it

Answer (score 1):

You can't access the `role_id` because it's a property on your User model, not on your controller. That's what the "Undefined property" error means. `$this` refers to the Controller object, not the User model.

`\Auth::user()->role_id` should work, granted that you've added the `role_id` attribute to the User model's `$fillable` array.

Comment: I've added role_id as $fillable attribute to User's model. You mean that instead $this->role_id I put  \Auth::user()->role_id ? When I replace, and add use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;  to the HomeController header I got this error 
Trying to get property 'role_id' of non-object

Comment: Look into Gates.  It's a very easy way to determine permission through a laravel app.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you tried to use without define `$role_id` in this `HomeController` Class.

Second, you can't use auth middleware when before finish constructing, because constructors are created before middlewares, that's why its returning null.[check here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39175252/cant-call-authuser-on-controllers-constructor)

```
use Auth;

class Homecontroller extends Controller{

   private $role_id;

   public function __construct(){

   }

   public function __toString(){
      $authUser = Auth::user(); // or Auth::user()->role_id;
      $this->role_id = $authUser->role_id;

      if($this->role_id=="1"){
        $this->middleware('admin'); 
      }

      if($this->role_id=="2"){
        $this->middleware('user0');  
      }

      if($this->role_id=="3"){
        $this->middleware('user1'); 
      }

      if($this->role_id=="4"){
        $this->middleware('user2'); 
      }

      return $this->role_id;
   }
}
```

and another way should be with this [middleware-parameters](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/middleware#middleware-parameters)

Happy coding ~!