# Laravel 'Auth::user()' displaying false in '__construct' of a controller

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, controller

**Problem**

Laravel's method `Auth::check()` is returning `false` in the `__construct` method of my controller but its returning `true` in any other method used (While i'm logged in of course). I'm assuming the Auth facade isn't quite ready for use when the program hits the `__construct` method? Or something like that.

For reference `Request::path()` is working correctly in the same place that `Auth::check()` returns false.

**Examples**

```
public function __construct()
{
    dd(Auth::check()); // Returns False
    dd(Request::path()); // Returns full path as expected
}

public function dashboard()
{
    dd(Auth::check()); // Returns True
}
```

**Question**

How do I make Laravels `Auth -> 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth'` available for use in the `__construct` method of my controller.

Comment: This might be the answer to your problem: [Can't call Auth::user() on controller's constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39175252/cant-call-authuser-on-controllers-constructor)

Comment: @vivek_23 thank you for the flow of possible duplicates its really helping

Comment: _As an alternative, you may define a Closure based middleware directly in your controller's constructor_ quote from Laravel doc [upgrade to 5.3](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/upgrade)

Comment: @HamzStramGram i tried this and it didn't seem to work for me, i solved this however by creating a middleware for the action that i wanted.

Answer (score 0):

I've decided to move this to middleware since it seems since Laravel 5.3 you can no longer access `Auth` in a controllers construct method.