# Laravel fetch and bind values with every view automatically

Tags: laravel, cookies, view, extract, bind

I have a backend/admin Laravel application which uses cookies value to set the state of the sidebar to be opened, collapsed or floating.

What I am trying is that I am fatching the value from cookies based on the token of the logged in user. I tried writing the code `$this->userToken = Auth::user()->token;` in the `__construct()` of the controller but it doesn't work. I get this error `Trying to get property of non-object`.

However if I write the code in any method of the controller it works without an error. I googled this issue and found several solutions but none of them were able to fix it.

I tried View composer as well.

Controller:

```
/**
 * Private variables
 */
private $controller  = "";
private $action      = "";
private $arrayCookie = "";

public function __construct(Route $route)
{
    /** 
     * Middlewares
     */
    $this->middleware('auth');
    $this->middleware('cookies');
    $this->middleware(function ($request, $next) {
        $userToken         = Auth::user()->token;
        $this->arrayCookie = $request->$userToken;

        return $next($request);
    });

    /** 
     * Extracting current controller & action from the namespace
     */
    list($controller, $method) = @explode("@", $route->getActionName());

    /** 
     * Assigning values to private variables
     */
    $this->controller = preg_replace('/.*\\\/', '', $controller);
    $this->action     = preg_replace('/.*\\\/', '', $method);
}

public function <method>()
{
    ...
    # rendering view
    return view(self::DIRECTORY . "create", [
        ...

        **'arrayCookie' => $this->arrayCookie,**

        ...
    ]);
    ...
}

...
```

View:

```
...

<div id="main"<?php
    # fetching cookie -> sidebar-floating
    if(!empty($arrayCookie['sidebar-floating']) && $arrayCookie['sidebar-floating'] == true)
    {
        echo ' class="sidebar-floating"';
    }
?>>

...
```

Comment: `Auth` is made available in the middleware of your application. This happens **after** your class is constructed. This is why it isn't available in the constructor. More information can be found in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39175252/cant-call-authuser-on-controllers-constructor).

Comment: Thanks @Lewis, I'll try this. But if this works then I'll still have to put that code in every controller and pass the values in every method along with other values. Is there any other way where I do not need to copy the code in every controller?

Comment: @Pummi could you include the related code (controller / view) in order to have a better understanding of the issue?

Comment: @Pummi Yes, you could create a middleware. Alternatively, I assume that your controllers extend the default controller. Put your code in there and every controller that extends it will have access.

Comment: @HCK I have included the controller and view code. @Lewis, I have tried to add that in the parent controller as well but it did not work, here is the parent controller ```class Controller extends BaseController``` where i included the code in the ```__construct```.

Comment: @Pummi  did you tried adding `use Auth` above of your class?

Comment: Thank you @all, It's working. The mistake I was making is that I wasn't including ```use Auth``` in the ```BaseController``` as suggested by @JoefreyR.Ramos. Also I copied the ```__construct``` from other controller but forgot to remove its parameters.

Comment: @Pummi good to hear that maybe you can upvote my answer. :)

Comment: Sure, @JoefreyR.Ramos. :)