# How to access a field data from users table from a controller in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I have `DashboardController` where I need to fetch dashboard data based on a field `site` from `users` table for the logged in user.

This is my controller:

```
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class DashboardContoller extends Controller {
    protected $today;
    protected $site;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->middleware('auth');
        $this->today = date("Y-m-d");
        $this->site = auth()->user()->site; // this line is showing error
    }

    // Rest of my code goes here
}
```

It is giving me "Trying to get property 'site' of non-object" error when I try to access the field `site`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39175252/cant-call-authuser-on-controllers-constructor

Comment: Suberb, @JohnLobo! It solved my issue. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP parse/syntax errors; and how to solve them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050071/php-parse-syntax-errors-and-how-to-solve-them)

Comment: A small recommendation, never use `$this->middleware();` in a controller, as that is the `route` responsibility (who allow access to or run any middleware), not the controller... If you were able to access that controller, then it means that the routing layer allowed you, do you see my logic ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I had to move the line of code `auth()->user()->site` to `index()` function next to the constructor as @John suggested. Also removed `middleware` from the controller and added to the `web.php`.

```
public function __construct(){
    $this->today = date("Y-m-d");        
}

public function index(){
    $this->sites = Helper::getSites(auth()->user()->site);
    return view('division.dashboard.index')->with($data);
}
```